# Evaluate a 3D spline in Matlab

Tags: matlab, spline, evaluate

I'm struggling to find a solution to this problem since the last week and still got no result.

I have a 3d spline in matlab, necessarily defined (I can't change the representation) with the spap2 command, and I need to evaluate the spline itself given two coordinates (say x and y). I tried to use the fnval command with different sintaxes but with no success.

Example: I'd like to get the z at x=26, y=120 with the spline defined with

```
x=[13 56 90 67 89 43];
y=[112 156 136 144 144 128];
z=[63 95 48 78 77 15];
sp = spap2(4,4,1:length(x),[x; y; z]);
```

Could anyone help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Ihave not used the function before, but are you sure you are using spap2 correctly? it seems you need to give it a knot secuence as the first parameter, which you are not doing. Once you have it you shoul evaluate it using fnval(sp, ...) but I tink you problem now is the spine... Check this tutorial: http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/toolbox/splines/tutor9.html

Comment: Yes, in the first parameter you can give the number of polynomial pieces instead of the knot sequence (the program itself chooses a knot sequence) so I think that the spline is not the problem (but I can be wrong). Anyway thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A spline is an approximation. It does not need to go through the coordinates (x=26,y=120) at all. There is no immediate definition of what z value would be reasonable for these (x, y) values.

Your x values (independent values) are `1:length(x)` and the output (dependent values) is `[x;y;z]`.

For example `fnval(sp, 1.5)` gives a reasonable output.

Comment: Thank you, I knew that there was no immediate definition of z with given (x,y) values, but I was searching a solution considering the (x,y) values that are actually the dependent values. I didn't focus on the fact that the x parameter of the function actually represented the real independent coordinates.